# OAuth Integration with JFrog Artifactory

Tags: oauth, openshift, token, artifactory

I have just deployed JFrog Artifactory using Docker file on AWS-Openshift Environment.

I need to integrate Artifactory with the OpenShift OAuth service.

Could anyone please guide me how to proceed on this?

I can check these options from below/document.

OAuth integration settings, in the Admin module, select Security | OAuth SSO.

I configured using above and getting error -

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."}
```

=====================================================================

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list all users in the cluster",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "users"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

FROM rhel7:latest

```
MAINTAINER Naveen Kumar 06 <naveen.sr@tech.com>

RUN set -x \
   && yum -y install tar unzip \
    && yum -y update \
    && yum -y clean all 


#java
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR 8
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MINOR 102
ENV JAVA_VERSION_BUILD 14

RUN mkdir -p /opt \
  && curl --fail --silent --location --retry 3 \
  --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie; " \
  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-b${JAVA_VERSION_BUILD}/server-jre-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  | gunzip \
  | tar -x -C /opt \
  && ln -s /opt/jdk1.${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.0_${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR} ${JAVA_HOME}

#jfrog-artifactory-pro-4.12.1.zip

#https://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro/org/artifactory/pro/jfrog-artifactory-pro/4.12.1/jfrog-artifactory-pro-4.12.1.zip 

ENV ARTIFACTORY_VERSION 4.12.1
ENV ARTIFACTORY_HOME /artifactory-pro-${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}

#ADD http://dl.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-pro-${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}.zip?direct artifactory.zip

ADD https://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro/org/artifactory/pro/jfrog-artifactory-pro/4.12.1/jfrog-artifactory-pro-4.12.1.zip artifactory.zip

RUN unzip artifactory.zip

RUN sed -i -e 's/Xmx2g/Xmx512m/g' artifactory-*/bin/artifactory.default

#artifactory-oss-4.12.1/tomcat/webapps/

RUN chmod +x /artifactory-pro-${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}/bin/artifactory.sh

# Expose the default endpoint
EXPOSE 8081

WORKDIR /artifactory-oss-${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}

RUN chmod -R 777 /artifactory-pro-4.12.1/

# Run the embedded tomcat container
ENTRYPOINT /artifactory-pro-${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}/bin/artifactory.sh
```

Regards
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

The problem in our case is that OpenShift authentication does not provide id_token. This is the reason for your problem. We wrote a proxy to deliver to Artifactory from OpenShift OAuth the answer that it was expecting.

Be aware that Artifactory uses java.net.HttpURLConnection to connect to OpenID provider and Apache HTTP Client. That class reads from the System Properties the typical proxy settings

```
"https.proxyHost"
"https.proxyPort"
"https.proxyUser"
"https.proxyPassword"
```

To set them in Artifactory edit the artifactory.bat in /artifactory-home/bin

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC    -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=myProxyPort -Dhttps.proxyUser=myProxyUser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=XXXX
```